# TypeError: JwtStrategy is not a constructor; NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt

I am trying to make a MEAN Stack (Nodejs,Mongo,Angular app) and right now I am trying to make the API Authentication and Token.
I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pdFXmTfkeE&t=185s  and my passport.js look like that right now:

```
passport.js 

const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Stategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');


module.exports = function (passport) {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt");
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

I am receiving the next error :

> TypeError: JwtStrategy is not a constructor
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\dan.diaconu\MakeIT\api\config\passport.js:10:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\dan.diaconu\MakeIT\api\app.js:28:29)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:609:3

Any ideas please ? Thank you! :)

Comment: replace: `const { Strategy:JwtStrategy, ExtractJwt} = require('passport-jwt');`
instead of:
`const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Stategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;`

Answer (score 4):

You have typo in the `require` statement `Stategy`.

Change

`const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Stategy;`

to

`const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;`